# Flagging for Moderator Attention in Review Mode

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

When in /review, I sometimes see a post that's a better fit for foo.stackexchange.com. Normally, the way I would handle this is by marking it as off-topic and suggesting that it be a better fit for foo.SE.

However, I can only do this if I have sufficient reputation in foo.SE. If I do not have sufficient reputation in foo.SE, then my only other option is to flag it for moderator attention and suggest that the post belongs in foo.SE, so that a mod can migrate the post. This method is fine for posts that I see normally. However, there is no `Flag` option in /review, which means that I have to navigate to the original post and then flag it for migration. This is more tedious than it should be.

Am I missing something? am I using /review wrong? Or should this be a new feature in /review?